# How to get a jQuery modal overlay to not push the scrollbar around?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, modal-dialog

I am using [Vex.js](http://github.hubspot.com/vex/api/basic/) to have a modal dialog on a webpage that just works. It uses jQuery, it is working but there is one thing that really annoys me. If it is on a page that is long enough to have a scrollbar, when the dialogue pops up it shoves the scrollbar to the right, and when it is exited everything jerks back left. ^^click on the buttons on the page I linked, you will see exactly what I mean. I looked at [this](http://minus.com/i/jN5pPEWjJQGO) site, which also has a modal dialogue box (click on the smallish share button at the bottom of the image), and when it pops up the overlay seems to be sitting under the scrollbar and not upsetting things. I'm assuming they are using jQuery as well since this seems to be the standard(not too keen on the HTML5 implementation of this myself). How are they getting it to do this? I inspected it with dev tools and to the best of my meager ability couldn't find any properties that are doing this in the css.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CSS:

```
body.vex-open {
    overflow: visible !important;
 }
```

Comment: Works. Thank you! Why is this not the default?